# Finding rational $p$ and $q$ that satisfy $(p+3\sqrt 7)(5+q\sqrt 7)=9\sqrt 7-53$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How do I find rational $p$ and $q$ that satisfy this equation?
> $$(p+3\sqrt 7)(5+q\sqrt 7)=9\sqrt 7-53$$

The equation is equal to:
$$5p+15\sqrt 7+pq\sqrt 7+3q\sqrt 7=9\sqrt 7-53$$
What can I do next to find what $p$ and $q$ are equal to?

I know that since there are three $\sqrt 7$'s here, and I know that they have something to do with the answer; so, what can I do next to find out the values of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: You would combine the $\sqrt 7$ terms together, and then take all $\sqrt 7$ terms to one side. Then you get $5p +53 = \sqrt 7(-6-pq-3q)$. Now, if $p,q$ are rational(otherwise you can't find $p,q$ uniquely so surely that is the case) , then $\sqrt 7 = \frac{5p+53}{-6-pq-3q}$ would be $\sqrt 7$ expressed as a rational number, which we know is not possible. So what must happen for this  division to fail? What can you conclude from here?

Comment: Straightforward algebraic manipulation:  $$p = \frac{-21 q-6 \sqrt{7}-53}{\sqrt{7} q+5}$$

Comment: It should be $$.. \ + 3q \color{red}{\sqrt{7}^{2}} = 9\sqrt{7} - \ ..$$

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Sorry guys, I forgot to mention that p and q are both rational.

Answer (score 1):

$5p+15\sqrt7+pq\sqrt7+3q\sqrt7=9\sqrt7-53$
$\Rightarrow$$\sqrt7(15+pq+3q)+5p=9\sqrt7-53$
Two irrational numbers are equal iff their rational and irrational parts are equal.
$\Rightarrow$ $$5p+21q=-53 \;and\; 15+pq+3q=9$$
On solving these equations, we get $p=-10.6 \;and\; q=0.789$

Comment: that seems to be right, but don't the variables have 2 values? they are rational btw

Comment: Your second equation is defective. it's $5p+21q=-53$.

Comment: The question had an arithmetic error. The first equation (copies from the question) is already incorrect.

Comment: Instead of "rational part" and "irrational part" of an irrational number, consider restricting the conversation to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ (a vector space) and refer to the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt{7}$. Although in the context it's possible to determine what you mean, the "irrational" part of a generic irrational number doesn't seem to have meaning.

Answer (score 1):

First, as mattos mentioned in a comment, your last equation should look like

$$5p + 15\sqrt7 + pq\sqrt7 + 3q\sqrt7^2 = 9\sqrt7 - 53$$

which simplifies to

$$(5p + 21q + 53) + (pq + 6)\sqrt7 = 0$$

Now you use the fact that two real numbers are equal if and only if their rational and irrational parts are equal. Since $p$ and $q$ are rational you must have

$$5p + 21q + 53 = 0, \; \; pq+ 6 = 0$$

You can solve this to get $p$ and $q$. There will be two pairs of solutions, in fact.

[image]

Comment: I put in a picture

Comment: Instead of "rational part" and "irrational part" of an irrational number, consider restricting the conversation to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ (a vector space) and refer to the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt{7}$. Although in the context it's possible to determine what you mean, the "irrational" part of a generic irrational number doesn't seem to have meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa!  IMPORTANT  $(3\sqrt 7)\cdot (q\sqrt 7) = 3q\sqrt 7^2 = 3q\cdot 7=21q\ne 3q\sqrt 7$.

So we have $5p + 15 \sqrt 7 +pq \sqrt 7 + 21q = 9\sqrt 7 -53$

Now rewrite that as $(15+pq)\sqrt 7 + (5p+21a) = 9\sqrt 7 - 53$

The trick is that no matter how you add up the rational multiples of $\sqrt 7$ you will always get a a rational multiple of $7$ and no matter how you add up the rationals you get a rational and you can never "breakup" or mixup the rational multiples of $\sqrt 7$ and rationals.  (They are like oil and vinegar.)

So if $M\sqrt 7 + Q = A\sqrt 7 + B$ and $M,Q,A,B$ are all rational we must have $M=A$ and $Q = B$.

> Pf:  Suppose $M\ne A$ then $M\sqrt 7 - A\sqrt 7 = B-Q$ then $\sqrt 7(M-A) = B-Q$ and $M-A \ne 0$ so $\sqrt 7 =\frac {B-Q}{M-A}\in \mathbb Q$ which is a contradiction.  So $M = A$ and so $M\sqrt 7 + Q = M\sqrt 7 + B$ so $Q=B$.

So we just have to solve $15 +pq  = 9$ and $5p+21q  = -53$.

$p = \frac {-53-21q}5$ and so

$15 - \frac {53+21q}5q = 9$

$75 - 53q -21q^2 = 45$

$21q^2 +53q -30 = 0$ so $q = \frac {-53 \pm \sqrt {53^2+4*30*21}}{42}=\frac {-53\pm 73}{42}= \frac {20}{21}$  or $-\frac {126}{42}=3$ and so

$p =\frac {-53 -20}5 = \frac {-73}5$ or $p=\frac {-53+63}5= 2$.

So $(p,q) =(\frac {-73}5,\frac {20}{21})$ or $(p,q) = (2,-3)$.

Comment: So we just have to solve $15 +pq  = 9$ and $5p+21q  = -53$.......so that $p=2, q=-3$ is a correct solution.

Comment: Did I screw up arithmetic?  $15+2*(-3)=9$ check and $5*2 + 21*(-3)= -53$.  Check.  Yep.... some arithmetic error some where.  Lessee.  $p = \frac {-53-21q}5 = -\frac {53+21q}5$.  That's it.  A sign error.  Effin' hate them but what can one do? The only alternative is to be careful and not make stupid errors but thats not gonna happen....